# Do married men stop saying a bracha on their *tallit katan*?

Tags: blessing, marriage, tallit-gadol, men-male, tallit-katan

This question concerns the Ashkenazic practice.

I was always told that the *tallit katan* (worn under clothing, every day, starting in preschool years) got the bracha of *al mitzvat tzitzit*, but the *tallit gadol* (worn over clothing during prayers, starting when one is married) gets *lehit'atef batzitzit*. (The Ramah in Shulchan Aruch says we're not sure the minor garment warrants the proper blessing of *lehit'atef*.)

I was also told that once you get married, you stop saying a bracha on the *talit katan* and just rely on the bracha you'll say that day on the *talit gadol*.

Is that the standard practice? And where is the source please? (I looked at a shulchan aruch and saw it talked about that occasionally you *can* wait for the later bracha to include it, but did it say that you *should*?)

Comment: Related near-duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12810

Comment: The only connection in Minhog Ashkenaz between tallis and marriage is the fact that the kallah gives the choson a new tallis at the se'udas sivlonos, and the chuppah (where the brochos are said, etc.) is a tallis. What you are referring to is the practice that came in to being because of a material shortage in Europe that many communities forgot the reason for later on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mishnah Berurah (8:24)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&pgnum=27) says that "in our times" it is customary to do so, and says that indeed it's better to do it this way. First of all, he says, if you say the two berachos back-to-back, then then one of those berachos is unnecessary. Second, even if you put the tallis katan and tallis gadol on at different times (and say the two berachos separately), the tallis katan may not be suitable for saying a berachah on anyway: it might be closed too far up the sides, or too small, or you might have slept in it.

See also Dayan Raskin's [notes to the Rav's siddur](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&hilite=c1daaf35-f918-4152-b83d-9ccda8bb08de&st=%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA&pgnum=89), that another good reason for this practice is because one may put on the tallis katan while his hands are still unclean (before washing negel vasser), or before daybreak. In either of those cases he would have to touch the tzitzis later on (למשמש בציציותיו) and say the berachah "al mitzvas tzitzis," but it is a subject of dispute whether touching them is effective for this purpose.

Comment: "the tallis katan may not be suitable for saying a berachah on anyway: it might be closed too far up the sides, or too small, or you might have slept in it."  Then why say it before you are married? And why not always wear the Talit Gadol? And what if you know it's not any of those things?

Comment: Thanks! I was skimming through and must have missed that mishna brurah.

Comment: @avi: dunno, but maybe the difference is that before marriage there's no choice in the matter (since that's the only tallis you're wearing), while afterwards you can get away with just the berachah on the tallis gadol. In other words, אין דנין אפשר משאי אפשר. (Of course, why it's אי אפשר to wear a tallis gadol before marriage... that's a whole 'nother issue.)

Comment: @Alex I think the truth is really not so complicated. It's not done that way because that isn't what the people were doing. The Mishna Berurah here sounds more like a 'yesh daat' to explain the 'current' practice.

Comment: @avi See the Darkei Moshe on OC 9 who implies that he started the practice to deal with people making tallitot ketanot that were not really kosher in order to avoid brachot levatalot. Nowadays our tallitot ketanot are much more kosher and warrant there own bracha the way it should be: over la'asiyatan.

Comment: @avi Sorry it's Darkei Moshe OC 8 and I'm not seeing it so clearly inside. See how the Mishna Brura references it in OC 16 sk 1 and let me know what you think.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't have a copy of Darkei Moshe. But I remember there being many reasons why a particular pair of tzizit may not be kosher according to various opinions, and even today's tzizit often fail to be kosher by strict standards. (Like not being made out of wool for example)

Comment: @avi Wool is only a de'oraita/derabanan question. everyone agrees it is obligated, just maybe not biblically. The bigger issue is size, and yes some question many of today's tallitot ketanot as being too small, but in general they are kosher according to many more opinoins.

Comment: Alex, if we are so worried about the viability of a given tallis kattan to not say a bracha, why do we allow people to wear them outside an eruv on Shabbat?

Comment: @DoubleAA: indeed, if the tallis katan is too small, or closed too far up the sides, etc., then you can't wear it outside on Shabbos ([M.B. 10:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=47&hilite=)).

Comment: @Alex Yes, but my point is I see way more people being machmir to avoid the bracha than I do who are machmir to not wear their same tallitot ketanot outside of an eruv on Shabbat. Wouldn't you expect the Shabbat chumra to be more important?

Answer (score 0):

The ruling of the Alter Rebbe is when one starts wearing a tallis gadol they no longer recite the bracha on the tallis katan. The source in the sidur. Can be found in the blue annotated edition of Tehilas Hashem on page 9

Comment: I just see this  ואם לובשו מיד בקומו בעוד שאין ידיו נקיות כדי שלא ילך ד' אמות בלא ציצית מברך על טלית גדול ויכוין לפטור גם את זה וכן אם לובשו קודם אור היום שאינו זמן ציצית: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/piskey