# New Beracha on Tzizit

Tags: blessing, tzitzis

If I already made a beracha on a talit katan but then I shower and then put on a new talit katan, do I make a new beracha?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13589/759

Answer (score 0):

In Ezor Yisroel page 40 he says that if putting on the same pair as before taking a shower then one doesn't need to say a new blessing unless one takes an exceptionally long time and removed one's mind from the Tzitzit. But if you put on a new pair you should say a blessing as you didn't have in mind to wear this pair and it wasn't part of the blessing in the morning.