# What consititutes a "complete interruption" between talis katan and gadol?

Tags: blessing, tallit-gadol, hefsek-interruption, tallit-katan

[This page](http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=1813&nl=1) references an uncited location in the Mishneh Berura and says that "[O]ne only makes separate berachos if there is a complete interuption between the talis katan and gadol. Just walking to shul would not meet that criteria." For the purpose of deciding whether to say both berachas, what constitutes a "complete interuption"?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/tallit-katan-and-tallit-brachot#comment20640_12814

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11303/759 and comments there

Comment: Why not comment on the posting and ask him?

Answer (score -1):

It's *MB* 8:28 and :33–34. He says speaking about an unrelated matter would constitute sufficient interruption according to some but not others. He says also that, although walking to the synagogue does not constitute a sufficient interruption, some hold that a new blessing would be said because the original blessing was in a different location. But he does not list any specific activity that would constitute sufficient interruption according to everyone. (*Rama* there, however, says that removing the first garment before donning the second would necessitate a blessing on the second.)

Note, anyway, that the practice I'm familiar with (cited with approval by *MB* :24) is that someone planning to say a blessing when donning the *talis gadol* at *shacharis* does not say a blessing when donning the *talis katan* even if there is significant interruption between the two acts of donning.

Comment: According to the MB, if one did not know that he would have an unrelated conversation on the way to shul, how would he know to say the beracha on the talis katan?

Comment: @Daniel Isn't your question backwards? The talis katan comes first (IME at least). You say a bracha before doing a mitzva, and if something interrupts, you say a new bracha later on a new mitzva.

Comment: @Daniel, I've edited to clarify. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @msh210 I don't see how your edits helped with Daniel's comment. The practice you cite, while tangentially related, is not part of an answer to this question.

Comment: (As I noted [elsewhere](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/tallit-katan-and-tallit-brachot#comment23374_12814) it is doubtful if the Mishna Berura would still approve of the latter practice today.)